# onDraw drawLine base on text Position

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw

I have a custom textView with a drawn line top of its view.

how can I draw line base on text(text in textView) Gravity and position...

in the example, I want to draw a line where text starts and end my drawn line where the text ends...

is it possible and if its yes how can I achieve this?

```
canvas?.drawLine(startOfText, 0f, stopOfText, 0f, paint)
```

Comment: see `Paint#getTextBounds`

Comment: @pskink do you have any example for this? because I tried this and find out getTextBounds is Void and returns nothing

Comment: have you read `getTextBounds()` method documentation? it explains how the result is returned

Comment: please post an example image of what you want to achieve